# How to parse XML in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

Using spark version 2.2 and Java 1.8

I have folder which contains many xmls and one XML file represents one record. So I want to parse the xmls and create a Spark Dataset for all the rows[1 XML = 1 record].

Input -

file1.xml

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <RECORD>
            <PROP NAME="product.url">
             <PVAL>url1</PVAL>
            </PROP>
           <PROP NAME="product.id">
             <PVAL>123</PVAL>
           </PROP>
           <PROP NAME="product.language">
             <PVAL>english</PVAL>
           </PROP>
          </RECORD>
```

file2.xml

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <RECORD>
             <PROP NAME="product.url">
               <PVAL>url1</PVAL>
             </PROP>
             <PROP NAME="product.id">
               <PVAL>456</PVAL>
             </PROP>
             <PROP NAME="product.language">
               <PVAL>french</PVAL>
             </PROP>
           </RECORD>
```

Expected Dataset/Dataframe: -

```
          product.url|product.id|product.language
          url1       | 123      | english  
          url2       | 456      | french
```

Comment: if the stucture is prety regular xpath can probably do what you want. you give it a path to a node say /RECORD/PROP/PVAL/ and you can get a list of elements get properties on elements and text elements

Comment: Can you please elaborate it.Thanks

Comment: [toots](http://www.baeldung.com/java-xpath)